# Composers alive 1050-1068?

Tags: choral-music, unknown-composer

I'm making a playlist of composers who were continuously alive for the past 1000 years: at least one, at most two composers alive in each year 1023 - 2023. I have a gap from 1050 to 1068. There's [Otloh of Sankt Emmeram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otloh_of_Sankt_Emmeram) but can't find recordings of his work in Spotify.

I would be happy for any tips/clues for tracking down medieval music from composers alive 1050-1068. Help me with my ridiculous project! Here's the playlist covering 1068-present (in 74 minutes of music!) https://open.spotify.com/playlist/0NwawrrXIuWzfHUkOd5r2Z